# Passing complex parameters to Controller method in ASP.Net MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

There is something fundamental I am failing to recall / grasp about front-> backend data transfer in ASP.Net.

I want to declare controller methods with complex types e.g.

```
 public JsonResult GetMyList(IEnumerable<Models.MyObject> filteredRows) {
```

and be able to call them from JQuery/javascript via AJAX, using JSON data.

Can I do this, or must I manually serialise/deserialise everything? Sometimes I forget which decade I am in and end up doing things manually that the framework now handles...

EDIT: (to save further "amusement") An example of the modern day "How" would be very helpful. When I look it up, there are so many answers of various vintages that I am not sure what the simplest way is!

Comment: Yes, of course you can do it.

Comment: See my edit :-)